# Get error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

i have problem with web app i building useing extjs.
i have this code:
[The Code](http://www.pasteall.org/29303/javascript)

ok the error i get is this:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined
this the stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined
Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:44348
Base.callParentext-all-debug.js:2891
Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:44877
Ext.Class.newClassext-all-debug.js:3188
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiateext-all-debug.js:3948
Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAliasext-all-debug.js:3898
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:1555
Ext.define.statics.createext-all-debug.js:44241
Ext.define.lookupext-all-debug.js:26969
Ext.define.bindStoreext-all-debug.js:70975
Ext.define.initComponentext-all-debug.js:70756
Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:15614
Base.callParentext-all-debug.js:2891
Ext.define.constructorext-all-debug.js:27103
Ext.Class.newClassext-all-debug.js:3188
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiateext-all-debug.js:3948
(anonymous function)ext-all-debug.js:1555
(anonymous function)PageList.js:35
```

Comment: Fixed i just reload file no idea why happend but its work:)

Answer (score 2):

storge is a function, it needs to be executed to return a store.
Try `store: storge(),`

Answer (score 0):

In your [snippet](http://www.pasteall.org/29303/javascript), if you delete the entirety of line 1, 17 and 18, then change line 34 to:

`store : store,`

your code will work fine.